# How to fix height of form when input is clicked and a border appear when input:focus?

Tags: html, css

I have a form with bootstrap classes in which a gradient border appear when the input is clicked or focus. But when the input is clicked the forms height also moves. I want the form to remain static when the border is displayed or not.

I have tried making the span background: transparent but then it does not show the border when input is focused.

---

```
<div class="box">
<div class="row">
<div class="gradient-box">
<span>
<input type="text" name="name"class="form-control" />
</span>
</div><br>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="gradient-box">
<span>
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" />
 </span>
 </div><br>
</div>
</div>
```

---

```
.gradient-box span {
align-items: center;
background: transparent;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
transition: background .5s ease;
width: 100%;
}

.gradient-box:hover span,gradient-box:focus span, gradient-box 
span:focus, gradient-box:active,form-control:focus  {
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #2c22d4 0%, #e875fb 100%);
padding: 3px;
}
.form-control{
background-color: #333333;
color: white;
}
```

I want the form stop changing its height when one of the input is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the padding, not the background. The padding only appears once focused so it moves the elements down. Move the `padding:3px` to the `.gradient-box span` at all times and it will not move

```
.gradient-box span {
    align-items: center;
    background: transparent;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: background .5s ease;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
}

.gradient-box:hover span,gradient-box:focus span, gradient-box 
span:focus, gradient-box:active,form-control:focus  {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #2c22d4 0%, #e875fb 100%);
}

.form-control{
    background-color: #333333;
    color: white;
}
```